# How do I stream 4 ports at the same time using zmq sockets while keeping track of where it came from?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, zeromq, pyzmq

Below is how I am currently streaming from multiple ports, the problem is I am receiving random packets, and they are not coming in one port than the next port when each port is continuously flowing. How would I reconfigure this so I can receive continuous packets from all ports?

```
procname = "STREAM"
URI = json.loads(config.get("Packet_Source", "uri"))
stopic = json.loads(config.get("Packet_Source", "subtopics"))
try:
    context = zmq.Context()
    sock = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    for uri_rx in URI:
        sock.connect(uri_rx)
        log.debug("Connected to " + str(uri_rx))
    for top in stopic:
        sock.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, top)
    log.info('Connected %s socket to RECEIVE data from %s' % ('SUB', str(URI)))
except Exception as e:
    warnings.warn('ZMQ ERROR IN collectstream')
    warnings.warn("[[[%s  ERROR]]]:  %s" % (procname, str(e)))
    warnings.warn('[[[%s]]] connection address: %s' % (procname, str(URI)))
    warnings.warn('Quiting Generator Engine, setting quit.value=True')
    quit.value = True

while not quit.value:
     radio_msg = sock.recv()
```